# How to divide the same COUNT when there is a different WHERE statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no Idea how to google this stuff so i hope someone can help.

**Table: PlayerMoves**

```
HandNr | PlayerName | move | amount | OrderOfExecution
---+----------------+------+--------+-----------------
 1 | Hans           |raises|
 1 | Hans           |raises|
 1 | Peter          |raises|
 1 | Hans           |raises|
 1 | Peter          |folds |
```

**Table: PlayersInTheHand**

```
HandNr | Betround
-------+------------
 1     | Preflop
```

**SELECT STATEMENT1**

```
Select playermoves.PlayerName,Count(playermoves.move) 
FROM playersinthehand,playermoves
WHERE playersinthehand.Betround= 'Preflop' and
      playersinthehand.handnr = playermoves.Nr
GROUP BY playermoves.PlayerName;
```

**SELECT RESULT**

```
PlayerName| Betround
-------+------------
 Hans     | 3
 Peter    | 2
```

**SELECT STATEMENT2**

```
Select playermoves.PlayerName,Count(playermoves.move) 
FROM playersinthehand,playermoves
WHERE playersinthehand.Betround= 'Preflop' AND
      playermoves.move = 'raises' or playermoves.move = 'calls'
     or playermoves.move = 'bets' and
playersinthehand.handnr = playermoves.Nr
GROUP BY playermoves.PlayerName;
```

**SELECT RESULT**

```
PlayerName| Betround
-------+------------
 Hans     | 3
 Peter    | 1
```

My expected Results should be (Count from Statement 2 divided by Count from Statement 1) *100

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
PlayerName| Betround
-------+------------
 Hans     | (3/3)*100 = 100%
 Peter    | (1/2)*100 = 50%
```

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Also remember that AND goes before OR.

Comment: There's no mechanism for uniquely identifying rows here. This problem is insoluble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional counting using `SUM(CASE WHEN <predicate> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

For example:

```
SELECT
  playermoves.PlayerName,
  100.0 *
  sum(case when playersinthehand.Betround = 'Preflop' AND
      playermoves.move = 'raises' or playermoves.move = 'calls' then 1 else 0 end
  ) /
  count(playermoves.move) as betround
FROM playersinthehand
join playermoves on playersinthehand.handnr = playermoves.Nr
WHERE playersinthehand.Betround= 'Preflop'
GROUP BY playermoves.PlayerName;
```

Result:

```
 PlayerName  betround  
 ----------- --------- 
 Hans        100.00000 
 Peter       50.00000
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mC2bLJRNvMe9V9KvuDaDq1/1).

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution and the keyword "conditional counting" for further reading/googling

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Maybe worth checking if you really need a join or just an 'exists'.

```
-- Auxiliary data for testing purposes
with PlayerMoves (handnr, playername, move) as(
    select 1, 'Hans','raises'from dual union all
    select 1, 'Hans','raises' from dual union all
    select 1, 'Peter','raises' from dual union all
    select 1, 'Hans','raises' from dual union all
    select 1, 'Peter','folds' from dual),
PlayersInTheHand (handnr, betround) as(
    select 1, 'Preflop ' from dual)

--Actual query
SELECT
    playername,
    round(SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN move = 'raises' THEN
                1
        END
    ) / COUNT(1) * 100, 2) betround
FROM
    playermoves pm
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            null
        FROM
            playersinthehand ph
        WHERE
            ph.handnr = pm.handnr
            AND ph.betround = 'Preflop'
    )
GROUP BY
    playername;
```